# Length of Ph. D. Application CV for Mid-Career Professionals

Tags: application, cv

I am applying for a Ph. D. program after a 10 year career of secondary classroom teaching - I have held several positions in that time should I cut some of these teaching experiences out to make my CV fit one page (the teaching experiences are not at the college level, and not necessarily directly in the program I am applying for).

Comment: What are the positions?

Comment: 2 english teaching positions and 2 school librarian positions.

Comment: Are you applying for a PhD in relevant fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike an American industry resume, an academic CV does not have a length limit.  It would be appropriate to list all your teaching experience.

Comment: A PhD applicant doesn't yet have an academic CV though

Comment: The CV they submit with their application should be an academic CV.

Answer (score 2):

> I am applying for a Ph. D. program after a 10 year career of secondary classroom teaching - I have held several positions in that time should I cut some of these teaching experiences out to make my CV fit one page

Rather than cutting them out, why not list them, but omit descriptions, e.g.,

- 2018 - 2020 Department Head, School, City
- 2012 - 2018 Senior XYZ, School, City
- 2000 - 2012 XYZ, School, City

The descriptions can be pushed elsewhere, e.g., into an opening sentence. Alternatively, if you were at the same school, then something like:

- 2000 - 2020 School, City

  I concluded my teaching career as **Department Head (2018-2020)**, having served as *Senior XYZ (2012-2018)* and *XYZ (2000-2012)*. Blah, blah, blah.

Even if you weren't at the same school, you could use something similar, e.g.,

- 2000 - 2020 Secondary classroom teaching

  I concluded my teaching career as **Department Head (2018-2020), School, City**, having served as *Senior XYZ (2012-2018), School, City* and *XYZ (2000-2012), School, City*. Blah, blah, blah.

**The key idea is to include all positions. Don't omit material, gaps don't look good. Compress instead.**

Comment: Most academic CVs don't have descriptions.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I must be looking at the wrong ones then: Perhaps that's country-, discipline, or seniority-specific.